# Correct pattern to check if an async Task completed synchronously before awaiting it

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a bunch of requests to process, some of which may complete synchronously.
I'd like to gather all results that are immediately available and return them early, while waiting for the rest.

Roughly like this:

```
List<Task<Result>> tasks = new ();
List<Result> results = new ();

foreach (var request in myRequests) {
  var task = request.ProcessAsync();
  if (task.IsCompleted)
    results.Add(task.Result);  // or  Add(await task)  ?
  else 
    tasks.Add(task);
}

// send results that are available "immediately" while waiting for the rest
if (results.Count > 0)  SendResults(results);

results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
SendResults(results);
```

I'm not sure whether relying on `IsCompleted` might be a bad idea; could there be situations where its result cannot be trusted, or where it may change back to `false` again, etc.?

Similarly, could it be dangerous to use `task.Result` even after checking `IsCompleted`, should one always prefer `await task`?  What if were using `ValueTask` instead of `Task`?

Comment: Is it important to handle multiple results in one method (SendResults)?  You can just await result and send each  individually..

Comment: In this made-up example it is not important to handle multiple results at once @alexm.

Comment: Awaiting each result individually would mean awaiting each request in turn. If each request takes a second and there are 10, the user would have to wait for 10 seconds. Starting all 10 and waiting for all of them would then take ~1 second. My goal here is to return some results even faster, e.g. because they are cached results that are available immediately (so e.g. 3 results sent after 100ms and 7 after ~1 second)

Comment: Are you looking for something like [Jon Skeet's `OrderByCompletion` method](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/01/16/eduasync-part-19-ordering-by-completion-ahead-of-time/)?

Comment: As a side note, in your example in case one task has failed, the exception of this task will be propagated immediately, and the rest of the tasks will continue running unobserved in a fire-and-forget fashion. Is this your intention?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias you raise a good point, I merely wanted to keep the example simple. Maybe write it as an answer, as one of the things that could go wrong / be aware of when using `task.Result` ?

Comment: @RichardDeeming interesting, thank you! But in my case, no. I have a bunch of potentially cached results available immediately that I want to return early, anything else is awaited together, there's no real point in sending each result individually as they become ready. But good to know!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm not sure whether relying on IsCompleted might be a bad idea; could there be situations where its result cannot be trusted...

If you're in a multithreaded context, it's possible that IsCompleted could return false at the moment when you check on it, but it completes immediately thereafter. In cases like the code you're using, the cost of this happening would be very low, so I wouldn't worry about it.

> or where it may change back to `false` again, etc.?

No, once a Task completes, it cannot uncomplete.

> could it be dangerous to use `task.Result` even after checking `IsCompleted`.

Nope, that should always be safe.

> should one always prefer `await task`?

`await` is a great default when you don't have a specific reason to do something else, but there are a variety of use cases where other patterns might be useful. The use case you've highlighted is a good example, where you want to return the results of finished tasks without awaiting all of them.

As Stephen Cleary mentioned in a comment below, it may still be worthwhile to use `await` to maintain expected exception behavior. You might consider doing something more like this:

```
var requestsByIsCompleted = myRequests.ToLookup(r => r.IsCompleted);

// send results that are available "immediately" while waiting for the rest
SendResults(await Task.WhenAll(requestsByIsCompleted[true]));
SendResults(await Task.WhenAll(requestsByIsCompleted[false]));
```

> What if were using `ValueTask` instead of `Task`?

The answers above apply equally to both types.

Comment: Even if `IsCompleted` would return `false` even though it just became `true`, that'd just mean that Task is processed later and not immediately. I.e. not an error, just a delay, possibly a performance problem. Not in my scenario, though.  Thanks for your answer!

Comment: `Result` is not recommended, since it wraps exceptions in an `AggregateException`. Prefer `await` (which would always run synchronously when `IsCompleted`) or `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`.

Comment: @StephenCleary Good point. I updated my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You could use code like this to continually send the results of completed tasks while waiting on others to complete.

```
foreach (var request in myRequests)
{
    tasks.Add(request.ProcessAsync());
}

// wait for at least one task to be complete, then send all available results
while (tasks.Count > 0)
{
    // wait for at least one task to complete
    Task.WaitAny(tasks.ToArray());

    // send results for each completed task
    var completedTasks = tasks.Where(t => t.IsCompleted);
    var results = completedTasks.Where(t => t.IsCompletedSuccessfully).Select(t => t.Result).ToList();
    SendResults(results);

    // TODO: handle completed but failed tasks here

    // remove completed tasks from the tasks list and keep waiting
    tasks.RemoveAll(t => completedTasks.Contains(t));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer John! However, you rely on `IsCompleted` and `Result` in it as well, and the point of my question is whether doing that is safe. If that is the case, then yes, your answer will do as you describe. My actual scenario isn't the one I put in the question, I just made a simplified example to demonstrate it.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior's answer is spot on: both of these are safe.  After I wrote the demo code, I saw that they had already posted a great answer, but I still wanted to share the code just in case it is helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Using only `await` you can achieve the desired behavior:

```cs
async Task ProcessAsync(MyRequest request, Sender sender)
{
     var result = await request.ProcessAsync();
     await sender.SendAsync(result);   
}

...

async Task ProcessAll()
{

   var tasks = new List<Task>();
   foreach(var request in requests) 
   {
      var task = ProcessAsync(request, sender);
      // Dont await until all requests are queued up
      tasks.Add(task);
   }
   // Await on all outstanding requests 
   await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

}
```

Comment: Indeed, but my actual scenario is different. The code in question is just an example to explain what I'm asking

Answer (score -1):

There are already good answers, but in addition of them here is my suggestion too, on how to handle multiple tasks and process each task differently, maybe it will suit your needs. My example is with events, but you can replace them with some kind of state management that fits your needs.

```
    public interface IRequestHandler
    {
        event Func<object, Task> Ready;
        Task ProcessAsync();
    }

    public class RequestHandler : IRequestHandler
    {
        // Hier where you wraps your request:
        // private object request;
        private readonly int value;

        public RequestHandler(int value)
            => this.value = value;

        public event Func<object, Task> Ready;

        public async Task ProcessAsync()
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000 * this.value);
            // Hier where you calls:
            // var result = await request.ProcessAsync();
            //... then do something over the result or wrap the call in try catch for example
            var result = $"RequestHandler {this.value} - [{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}]";

            if (this.Ready is not null)
            {
                // If result passes send the result to all subscribers

                await this.Ready.Invoke($"RequestHandler {this.value} - [{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}]");
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        var a = new RequestHandler(1);
        a.Ready += PrintAsync; 
        var b = new RequestHandler(2);
        b.Ready += PrintAsync;
        var c = new RequestHandler(3);
        c.Ready += PrintAsync;
        var d= new RequestHandler(4);
        d.Ready += PrintAsync;
        var e = new RequestHandler(5);
        e.Ready += PrintAsync;
        var f = new RequestHandler(6);
        f.Ready += PrintAsync;

        var requests = new List<IRequestHandler>()
        {
            a, b, c, d, e, f
        };

        var tasks = requests
            .Select(x => Task.Run(x.ProcessAsync));

        // Hier you must await all of the tasks
        Task
            .Run(async () => await Task.WhenAll(tasks))
            .Wait();
    }

    static Task PrintAsync(object output)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(output);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```